# How can I select a Tab in TTabControl from a right click

Tags: delphi

I have a popup menu associated with my `TTabControl`.  I want to be able select the tab and invoke the drop down in one Right Hand button click.  Other controls I seem to remember would have a right button select property.

Comment: The `OnClick` event responds to the left button, but `OnMouseDown` and `OnMouseUp` give you more context about buttons used. I would use OnMouseUp, since usually those actions responds to letting go of the button,

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `OnPopup` event handler of your `TPopupMenu`:

```
procedure TForm1.PopupMenu1Popup(Sender: TObject);
var
  TabIndex : integer;
  Pt : TPoint;
begin
  Pt := TabControl1.ScreenToClient(TPopupMenu(Sender).PopupPoint);
  TabIndex := TabControl1.IndexOfTabAt(Pt.X, Pt.Y);
  if(TabIndex <> -1) then
  begin
    TabControl1.TabIndex := TabIndex;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
type
  TTabControl = class(Vcl.ComCtrls.TTabControl)
  private
    FRightClickSelect: Boolean;
    procedure CNNotify(var Msg: TWMNotify); message CN_NOTIFY;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
  published
    property RightClickSelect: Boolean read FRightClickSelect write FRightClickSelect default False;
  end;

implementation

uses
  Winapi.CommCtrl;

{ TTabControl }

constructor TTabControl.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  FRightClickSelect := False;
end;

procedure TTabControl.CNNotify(var Msg: TWMNotify);
var
  Index: Integer;
  HitInfo: TTCHitTestInfo;
begin
  if FRightClickSelect and (Msg.NMHdr.code = NM_RCLICK) then
  begin
    HitInfo.pt := ScreenToClient(Mouse.CursorPos);
    Index := SendMessage(Handle, TCM_HITTEST, 0, LPARAM(@HitInfo));
    if (Index <> -1) and (HitInfo.flags <> TCHT_NOWHERE) then
      TabIndex := Index;
  end;
  inherited;
end;
```